# DB2 for i Triggers - Once per statement, but comparing before and after values

Tags: db2, database-trigger, db2-400, materialized-views

In DB2 for IBM i, is it possible to create a trigger which runs once per statement, but able to loop through all affected rows to determine if any values actually changed?

Use case is to update a Materialized Query Table (MQT) with a trigger on the underlying tables.  But we only want to refresh the MQT if values have actually changed.  If we create the trigger to run once per row, we are able to get the desired functionality.  But if we Insert, Update and/or Delete multiple rows at a time, the "Refresh" statement runs for each row.  And currently that takes about 10 seconds for this MQT on our system.

Just hoping there was a way to use a trigger set to run once per statement, yet still have access to the before and after values of each individual row.  I haven't been able to find anything which indicates whether it is or isn't possible.  Though I suspect it is not.

If there is some other way to automatically refresh MQTs in an efficient manner, I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
create table test (id int not null primary key, a int)@
create table test_mqt (cnt) as (select sum(a) from test) data initially deferred refresh deferred maintained by user@

insert into test values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1) with nc@

create or replace trigger test_aus 
after update on test
referencing 
new table as n
old table as o
for each statement
mode db2sql
begin atomic
  if (exists (select 1 from n,o where n.id=o.id and n.a<>o.a)) then
    refresh table test_mqt;
  end if;
end@

-- trigger IS NOT fired after the following update
update test set a=1 with nc@
-- the following select returns 0
select cnt from test_mqt@

-- trigger IS fired after the following update
update test set a=2 with nc@
-- the following select returns 6
select cnt from test_mqt@
```

Comment: Okay, so the references to `OLD TABLE` and `NEW TABLE` represent a single row at a time, but will always loop through each affected row without explicit iterative structures?

Comment: `n` and `o` here are the correlation names for the transition `tables` (new and old sets of affected rows), not individual affected `rows`. "Loop through each affected row" is made by the SQL `select` statement in the trigger definition.

Comment: I don't think having the trigger run a refresh makes sense...see my answer for an alternative.

Comment: @Charles My example was essentially on how to detect table changes with a `for each statement` trigger and run some statement, if they are detected. As for real MQT maintenance with triggers - it may be more complex solution. Obviously, we need `after insert` and `after delete` triggers and rewritten `after update` trigger as well, if we don’t use full refresh at some point, and want to maintain our MQT incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the documentation is [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzhctrigger.htm). However, depending on how you are trying to do this, there are some differences between the IBM i command `ADDPFTRG` and the SQL `CREATE TRIGGER`.

`ADDPFTRG` does not appear to support statement level triggers but `CREATE TRIGGER` does.

When using the statement level trigger, you can reference the affected rows with

```
REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS ___
            NEW TABLE AS ___
```

You can process the old and new table references with SQL statements just as if they were regular tables.

Just to be clear, **OLD TABLE** references affected rows as they were before the SQL statement ran, and **NEW TABLE** references affected rows as they will be after the SQL statment completes.

Comment: Thank you @jmarkmurphy.  So I've read through that documentation already, but what I didn't find intuitive is if I'm using `FOR EACH STATEMENT` as opposed to `FOR EACH ROW`, how do I still iterate through each affected row so I can compare the before and after values?

Comment: Thank you for trying to clarify.  But I'm not sure I understand how to iterate through each row.  Would I open a cursor based on the aliases I created in the definition?  So a cursor on `T1` if it were defined as `REFERENCING OLD TABLE AS T1...`?

Comment: Don't think about it as iterating through. Think in sets. Join them together and select the set of rows with differences. If any differences are returned, you would update your MQT, if the set comes back empty, then don't update the MQT.

Comment: However, you could still be refreshing that MQT **a lot**. It seems that if you want to keep things in sync, an MQT may not be the way to go, but rather a view or a table function.

Comment: Okay, so both `OLD TABLE` and `NEW TABLE` share the same structure as the table in question, but only contain the affected records and nothing else.  I think I got it now.  I was thinking those references represented the entire table, not just the rows which were affected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to have a trigger run the refresh...

The whole point of the trigger + MQT would be to have the trigger directly update the MQT table. That way you only have to deal with the exact rows that have changed; rather than force the DB to read the entire base table again.

```
create or replace trigger test_aus 
after update on test
referencing 
new row as n
old row as o
for each row
mode db2sql
begin atomic
  if n.a <> o.a then
    update test_mqt set cnt = cnt + n.a - o.a;
  end if;
end@
```

But note that if a change in `a` is all you are interested in, then you could define the trigger as

```
after update of a on test 
for each row
```

that way the trigger will only fire if a is actually updated.

If you've got more SQL set at a time updates being done than RPG (or SQL) single row updates, then maybe a statement trigger would be worthwhile...

Something like so:

```
create or replace trigger test_aus 
after update on test
referencing 
new table as n
old table as o
for each statement
mode db2sql
begin atomic
   update test_mqt 
     set cnt = cnt + (select sum(n.a - o.a) 
                        from N join O using(id)
                        where n.a <> o.a
                      );

end@
```

**Edit: Alternative to MQT**
I've never actually used an MQT in production, since the IBM i doesn't support system maintained MQTs.

In the scenario where you're interested in an updated aggregate,  Encoded Vector Indexes (EVI) with included aggregates may provide a better solution; as they are maintained automatically.

```
CREATE ENCODED VECTOR INDEX sales_fact_location_id_evi 
ON sales_fact(sale_location_id ASC) 
INCLUDE(SUM(sale_amount_measure))
```

The example above is from the article [Accelerated analytics - faster aggregations using the IBM DB2 for i encoded vector index (EVI) technology](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-accelerated-analytics-db2-evi-tech/index.html) .  It a good article and compares EVI to MQT for storing aggregates.

Comment: As for real MQT mantenance with triggers. Unfortunately, DB2 for IBM i still doesn’t have `refresh immediate` or `refresh deferred` with incremental maintenance MQTs as, for example, Db2 for LUW does. Because of this even for such a simplest case we need `after insert` and `after delete` triggers as well. But when things go slightly more complex, such a trigger logic may become too complex very soon, and we finally may decide to end up with a solution like firing full refresh at some point.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein agree that it is unfortunate that Db2 for i doesn't support system maintained MQT.  But if you need real-time updates to MQT, then triggers updating the MQT are the only option.  If real-time isn't needed, then a scheduled refresh (with either the refresh statement or a user program) is ok.  Having a trigger use the refresh command doesn't make sense.